# Use different sed replacement on one matched sed group

Tags: regex, sed

I'm an experienced software developer, but just now going back and gaining sed skills.

I have a file `text.txt` that contains lines in the form:

```
blah blah blah
key-1:foo-bar
key-2:foo-baz
more blah blah
```

I want to separate out key/value pair sushc as `key-1` and `foo-bar` and send them to the command `do-something`, except that I want to convert `foo-bar` to `foo_bar`!

To extract the key/value pairs currently I have something like this:

```
sed -nE 's/([^:]+):(.+)/\1 \2/p' test.txt
```

That would print:

```
key-1 foo-bar
key-2 foo-baz
```

So far so good. Now if I want to pass that to `do-something`, I suppose I could do something like this and pipe it to `xargs` or something:

```
sed -nE 's/([^:]+):(.+)/do-something -a \1 -b \2/p' test.txt | xargs #something or another
```

I haven't looked up the xargs part yet. Before I get there, I wonder: **How I can replace `-` with `_`, but only in the second sed matching group, not the first?**

Or is there a simpler *nix tool I can use? (I welcome advice on the xargs part to pass this to `do-something` as well.) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sed` allows you to replace the second and later occurrences of `-` in a line. Like this:

```
<test.txt sed -nE '/[^:]+:/ {s/-/_/2g; s/:/ / p}'
```

For your example data this approach may be enough; however it will fail if the second `-` is in the key (`key-3-4:foo`) or if the first `-` is in the value (`key5:bar-baz`).

A general approach that recognizes keys and leaves them intact is possible. My idea is:

```
<test.txt sed -nE '/^[^:]+:/ {
   h
   s/:.*/ /
   x
   s/[^:]+://
   s/-/_/g
   H
   g
   s/\n//
   p
   }'
```

Explanation:

- A line is loaded into the pattern space because this is what `sed` does.
- `/^[^:]+:/` – match lines starting with one or more non-colons followed by a colon; the rest of the code is grouped in `{}` which means the whole group will be executed for matching lines and ignored for non-matching lines.
- `h` – copy pattern space to hold space.
- `s/:.*/ /` – replace the colon (which is guaranteed to exist because of the preliminary matching) and everything after with a space character. This will match the first colon in the pattern space because this is how regular expressions work. In result the pattern space contains the key plus space.
- `x` – exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces. Now the whole line is again in the pattern space; the key plus space is held safely in the hold space.
- `s/[^:]+://` – remove everything up to the first colon in the pattern space. What's left is the value.
- `s/-/_/g` – replace all occurrences of `-` with `_`.
- `H` – append pattern space to hold space. There will be a newline character between the old content (the key plus space) and the appended string (the altered value).
- `g` – copy hold space to pattern space.
- `s/\n//` – remove the aforementioned newline character.
- `p` – print the current pattern space.

Notes:

- Hold space survives from one line to another but we overwrite it (`h`) each time we need to use it anew, so there's no need to clear it explicitly.
- Ask yourself if you want `g` in `s/-/_/g`.

Comment: "…replace the second and later occurrences of `-` in a line…" Kamil, I don't know how many `-` characters will be in the key. Your second, general approach is complex; I'll need to take a while to digest it, as it's way beyond my current grasp of sed.